# Yii2: How to avoid 400 bad request in multisite use case?

Tags: php, yii2

I try to use one copy of Yii2 as multisite engine (one CMS, several domain-depended configs).
But when I send some **`ActiveForm`** in a controller action, I see **Bad Request 400**.
When I add _csrf field in simple HTML form and try to send it in an action, it works fine.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: Is this a case of posting the form to another origin (which is normally a bad idea)?

Comment: No, this is not a CSRF-form. I guess a cause of this problem is a session name. Or may be another session parameter is one. I am trying to verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution: I just name session with unique string for every domain.
This is done by editing domain-depended configs.

```
return [
    'components' => [
        ...
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'domain_name_session',
        ],
        ...
    ],
];
```

Comment: This is another problem with multi-site, always make sure to uniquely identify your cookies else they will overwrite each other

Comment: Thank you, I will make it too